# Batch Script Reading Comma as Number

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to sort some data by finding year structures and recording information relative to their position.  I have it mostly ironed out, except that it keeps detecting the date "May 15, 2021" and flags "15," as a matching value even with a "greater than 1000" check.  (The "15," is in the check token, the "2021" isn't considered).

```
for /f "tokens=4-11 delims= " %%A in (pdf.txt) do (

        IF %%C LSS 2020 (IF %%C GTR 1000 (

                 echo %%A %%B>>output.txt
                 echo .>>output.txt
                 echo .>>output.txt
        )
        )
)
```

I'm assuming my AND chain isn't set up properly, but the script works the same if I flip the order of operations.  I would just assume it would discard the "," as not a number, or assume that 15 is less than 1000.  Why does it think that "15," is between 1000 and 2020?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `15,` contains a non-numeric character and so forces `if` to string comparison. With string comparison, the result is correct.

Comment: `for /f "tokens=4-11* delims=, " %%A in (pdf.txt) do IF %%B LSS 2020 IF %%B GTR 1000 echo %%A %%B`